# Redis like a database

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

We have a redis with standalone configuration and I am using lettuce to connect with it. When we have one single user to access redis database the result api is fast, about 700ms, but when we have more then 5 users to consume this api that access redis database the time is increased more than 1 or 2 seconds.
How can garantee many users to consume my api without lost performance time?

PS: we have a java API (Spring boot) + lettuce + JPA without pool or explicit blocking operation. We have only findBy operations and may this API will be access about 30000 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the minimum idle connection pool and and active connection pool. Something like below:

```
lettuce:
  pool:
    max-active: 64
    max-idle: 64
    min-idle: 16
```

Try and fine tune these values as per your infrastructure and need. You might have to add connection pool dependency for lettuce cause it might not come by default. Something like `commons-pool2`

Comment: I've tried to do this config but it doesn't work. What I have done in wrong way? I've been upload my test project in: https://github.com/tiagoedez/redis-lettuce-pool-test

Comment: Are you able to see if the data is indeed being saved on you redis server? You can cross check by redis-cli.
Also, check your system configuration as 700ms for a local redis instance getting only 1 request is still too slow. Are enough resources being availed for your redis server?

Comment: Hi Ady I've got an instance aws and this redis-lettuce-pool-test first post returned in 1,3s after all post data returned in 143ms. But pool still isn't work